# How do I delete an item that is stored in the session?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I am using an array of structures in ColdFusion. Here is the code that I had tried. Can anyone help me to correct my code?

```
<cfif isDefined("remove")> //button in the cart page to remove a product
    <cflock scope="session" type="readonly" timeout="0200">
       <cfparam name="Session.cart">
       <cfloop query="#qProductSelected#"> //this is the query for getting productid from url
          <cfset sItem = structNew()> //this is my structure inside an array
          <cfset sItem.Image= Application.imageUrl&qProductSelected.ProductImage> //for getting image 
          <cfset sItem.ProductId =#ProductId#> //getting productid
          <cfset sItem.ProductImage = #Image#> //getting image
          <cfset sItem.ProductName = #ProductName#> //getting product name
          <cfset sItem.ProductDescription =#ProductDescription#> //getting productdescription
          <cfset sItem.quantity = form.qty> //storing quantity from form into the session
          <cfset structClear(sItem)> //finally i use structclear to clear the structure
        </cfloop>
   </cflock>
   <cflocation url="cart.cfm"> //redirecting to cart page itself
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to remove the 'cart' key from session, you can do this:

```
<cfset StructDelete(session,'cart')>
```

However, you are in a readonly lock so you'd need to change it to be an exclusive lock or not using locking... depends on the situation as to what makes sense there.

[StructDelete Docs](https://cfdocs.org/structdelete)

Comment: On newer version of ColdFusion you can do `session.delete('cart')`

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using cart. I guess you are storing the products as array of structures with details of products stored in structure.
If you want to remove a product from cart the code will look something like this

```
<cfset ArrayDeleteAt(session.arrCart,form.productsequenceincart) />
```

So for example if someone clicked the remove button of 3rd product the above code would do this -

```
<cfset ArrayDeleteAt(session.arrCart,3) />
```

It would delete third product from the cart array.

We don't need to loop over the product.